# MySQL query to determine classes remaining or completed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in my webinar_timing table in mysql database

start_time and end_time are of type datetime

```
   id  | webinar_id | start_time            | end_time
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  |     5      | 3/18/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/18/2015  7:00:00 PM
    2  |     5      | 3/19/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/19/2015  7:00:00 PM
    3  |     5      | 3/20/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/20/2015  7:00:00 PM
    4  |     5      | 3/21/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/21/2015  7:00:00 PM
    5  |     5      | 3/22/2015  6:00:00 PM | 3/22/2015  7:00:00 PM
    6  |    11      | 3/20/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/20/2015  9:00:00 PM
    7  |    11      | 3/21/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/21/2015  9:00:00 PM
    8  |    11      | 3/22/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/22/2015  9:00:00 PM
    9  |    22      | 3/25/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/25/2015  9:00:00 PM
   10  |    22      | 3/27/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/27/2015  9:00:00 PM
   11  |    22      | 3/29/2015  8:00:00 PM | 3/27/2015  9:00:00 PM
```

Basically, for each webinar, I want the total occurences and number of classes completed or remaining AND the NEXT upcoming class

Egs: When I run this query say at 3/21/2015 at 4:00 PM - this is the result I am expecting

```
 webinar_id | total     | Classes Completed | Next Class
----------------------------------------------------------
     5      |   5       | 3                 | 3/21/2015  6:00:00 PM
    11      |   3       | 1                 | 3/21/2015  8:00:00 PM
    22      |   3       | 0                 | 3/25/2015  8:00:00 PM
```

OR

```
 webinar_id | total     | Classes Remaining | Next Class
----------------------------------------------------------
     5      |   5       | 2                 | 3/21/2015  6:00:00 PM
    11      |   3       | 2                 | 3/21/2015  8:00:00 PM
    22      |   3       | 3                 | 3/25/2015  8:00:00 PM
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `SUM(IF(...))`

```
select webinar_id, count(*) AS total, 
SUM(IF(end_time<NOW(), 1, 0)) AS completed, 
SUM(IF(start_time>=NOW(), 1, 0)) AS remaining
from webinar_times
group by webinar_id;
```

You'll have to figure out whether you are looking at start_time or end_time and what to do with equals and little details like that...

Comment: Thanks Peter - thats exactly what I was looking for - I was going in the complete wrong direction of writing subqueries - thanks a ton - appreciate it

Comment: Hi Peter - in the same query is it possible for me to get the next class date - I have edited the question to reflect that - please advice

Comment: Please use a new question for additional issues. If this answered your (original) question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: sure will do that - I thought the question will sound repeated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), W.webinar_id, X.COMPLETED, Y.[NOT COMPLETE]
FROM #Webinars W
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'COMPLETED', webinar_id
       FROM #Webinars
       WHERE end_tim <= '3/18/2015  7:00:00'
       GROUP BY webinar_id) X
ON X.webinar_id = W.webinar_id  
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'NOT COMPLETE', webinar_id
       FROM #Webinars
       WHERE end_tim > '3/18/2015  7:00:00'
       GROUP BY webinar_id) Y
ON Y.webinar_id = W.webinar_id     
GROUP BY W.webinar_id, X.COMPLETED, Y.[NOT COMPLETE]
```